# Basic Text Classification with Python and NLTK

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

So I've been working with Python and NLTK to create a basic Document Classifier to assign a subject to a particular .txt file.

I'm new to Python so I'm sure the code isn't great but I'm having one particular problem. I changed the nine #ids to access text files automatically, because I was trying to add them all manually. However, instead of the nine #_feats lists containing the text of the files, they only contain the names of the files. The #ids contain both the names of the files and the text. I think the issue is with def_wordfeats(words) but I'm not sure what it is. Any help would be appreciated

```
import os
from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopset = list(set(stopwords.words('english')))


1ids = {}
2ids = {}
3ids = {}
4ids = {}
5ids = {}
6ids = {}
7ids = {}
8ids = {}
9ids = {}


path1 = "/Users/myname/Documents/Data Classifier Files/1/"

for name in os.listdir(path1):
    if name[-4:] == '.txt':
        f = open(path1 + "/" + name, "r")
        1ids[name] = f.read()
        f.close()

path2 = "/Users/myname/Documents/Data Classifier Files/2/"

for name in os.listdir(path2):
    if name[-4:] == '.txt':
        f = open(path2 + "/" + name, "r")
        2ids[name] = f.read()
        f.close()        

path3 = "/Users/myname/Documents/Data Classifier Files/3/"

for name in os.listdir(path3):
    if name[-4:] == '.txt':
        f = open(path3 + "/" + name, "r")
        3ids[name] = f.read()
        f.close()        

path4 = "/Users/myname/Documents/Data Classifier Files/4/"

for name in os.listdir(path4):
    if name[-4:] == '.txt':
        f = open(path4 + "/" + name, "r")
        4ids[name] = f.read()
        f.close()        

path5 = "/Users/myname/Documents/Data Classifier Files/5/"

for name in os.listdir(path5):
    if name[-4:] == '.txt':
        f = open(path5 + "/" + name, "r")
        5ids[name] = f.read()
        f.close()        

path6 = "/Users/myname/Documents/Data Classifier Files/6/"

for name in os.listdir(path6):
    if name[-4:] == '.txt':
        f = open(path6 + "/" + name, "r")
        6ids[name] = f.read()
        f.close()        

path7 = "/Users/myname/Documents/Data Classifier Files/7/"

for name in os.listdir(path7):
    if name[-4:] == '.txt':
        f = open(path7 + "/" + name, "r")
        7ids[name] = f.read()
        f.close()        

path8 = "/Users/myname/Documents/Data Classifier Files/8/"

for name in os.listdir(path8):
    if name[-4:] == '.txt':
        f = open(path8 + "/" + name, "r")
        8ids[name] = f.read()
        f.close() 

path9 = "/Users/myname/Documents/Data Classifier Files/9/"

for name in os.listdir(path9):
    if name[-4:] == '.txt':
        f = open(path9 + "/" + name, "r")
        9ids[name] = f.read()
        f.close()         

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words.split() if word not in stopset])

1_feats = [(word_feats(f), '1') for f in 1ids ]
2_feats = [(word_feats(f), "2") for f in 2ids ]
3_feats = [(word_feats(f), '3') for f in 3ids ]
4_feats = [(word_feats(f), '4') for f in 4ids ]
5_feats = [(word_feats(f), '5') for f in 5ids ]
6_feats = [(word_feats(f), '6') for f in 6ids ]
7_feats = [(word_feats(f), '7') for f in 7ids ]
8_feats = [(word_feats(f), '8') for f in 8ids ]
9_feats = [(word_feats(f), '9') for f in 9ids ]

trainfeats = 1_feats + 2_feats + 3_feats + 4_feats + 5_feats + 6_feats + 7_feats + 8_feats + 9_feats
classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)

print classifier.classify(word_feats(""))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong here:

```
1_feats = [(word_feats(f), '1') for f in 1ids ]
2_feats = [(word_feats(f), "2") for f in 2ids ]
3_feats = [(word_feats(f), '3') for f in 3ids ]
4_feats = [(word_feats(f), '4') for f in 4ids ]
5_feats = [(word_feats(f), '5') for f in 5ids ]
6_feats = [(word_feats(f), '6') for f in 6ids ]
7_feats = [(word_feats(f), '7') for f in 7ids ]
8_feats = [(word_feats(f), '8') for f in 8ids ]
9_feats = [(word_feats(f), '9') for f in 9ids ]
```

When iterating over a dictionary in python like you do, you are iterating over the keys. In your case, you are iterating over the file names rather than the actual content of the files.

Quick fix:

```
1_feats = [(word_feats(1ids[f]), '1') for f in 1ids ]
```